# MySQL query error on "INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS"

Tags: mysql, insert

Can someone tell me, why the first query executes fine, but the second query gives as error.
It even gives error with empty table

#1060 - Duplicate column name '3'.

**FIRST QUERY - OK**

```
INSERT INTO `ps_category_product` (`id_category`, 
                                   `id_product`, 
                                   `position`
                                   ) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '3','41895','2') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `ps_category_product` 
                            WHERE id_category =3 AND id_product =41895);
```

**SECOND QUERY - ERROR**

```
INSERT INTO `ps_category_product` (`id_category`, 
                                   `id_product`, 
                                   `position`
                                   ) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '3','116059','3') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `ps_category_product` 
                            WHERE id_category =3 AND id_product =116059
                 );
```

[image: estructure of table]

Comment: Because you have the value 3 twice. Use an explicit alias for your column names.

Comment: Can you tell me what the syntax is like? Thanks

Comment: synatx: 3 AS column_name

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? A better syntax is available in MySQL 8.

Comment: My versión is 5.7